CodeMirror: How to dynamically make specific lines readonly [2024]
I know there are already many topics about this, but they deal with older versions of CodeMirror.
What I intend to do:
The user can select code and use a context menu to make the lines readonly or editable.
For testing purposes, I have currently replaced the context menu function with a simple button.
In older posts on this topic, the "codemirror-readonly-ranges" extension was often referred to. This also works for me if I have already defined ranges before mounting. If I add ranges to the state, they are readonly, but all lines before them are also readonly even though I have only marked one line, for example. All characters after that are editable, as it should be.
In earlier versions you could use "onBeforeChange", this function is no longer available as far as I know.
"use client";
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import CodeMirror, { EditorView, ViewUpdate } from "@uiw/react-codemirror";
import { javascript } from "@codemirror/lang-javascript";
import { copilot } from "@uiw/codemirror-theme-copilot";
import readOnlyRangesExtension from "codemirror-readonly-ranges";
import { EditorState, SelectionRange } from "@codemirror/state";
import { basicSetup } from "@codemirror/basic-setup";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";

interface Props {
  initialCode: string;
}

const CodeEditor: React.FC<Props> = ({ initialCode }) => {
  const [code, setCode] = useState<string>(
    "// Start typing your code here\nimport React from 'react';\n"
  );
  const [editorView, setEditorView] = useState<EditorView | null>(null);
  const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState<EditorState | null>(null);
  const [readOnlyRanges, setReadOnlyRanges] = useState<
    Array<{ from: number | undefined; to: number | undefined }>
  >([]);

  // Function to get the selected range in a CodeMirror editor
  function getSelectedRange(editorView: EditorView): SelectionRange | null {
    const state: EditorState = editorView.state;
    const range: SelectionRange = state.selection.main; // Use .main to get the primary selection range

    if (range.empty) {
      console.log("No selection");
      return null;
    } else {
      console.log(`Selection from ${range.from} to ${range.to}`);
      return range;
    }
  }

  const handleChange = (value: string, viewUpdate: ViewUpdate) => {
    setCode(value);

    console.log(readOnlyRanges);
  };

  // add a read-only range
  const addReadOnlyRange = () => {
    if (editorView) {
      const range = getSelectedRange(editorView);
      if (range) {
        setReadOnlyRanges([
          ...readOnlyRanges,
          { from: range.from, to: range.to },
        ]);
      }
    }
  };

  // const getReadOnlyRanges = (
  //   targetState: EditorState
  // ): Array<{ from: number | undefined; to: number | undefined }> => {
  //   return [
  //     {
  //       from: undefined, //same as targetState.doc.line(0).from or 0
  //       to: targetState.doc.line(2).to,
  //     },
  //     {
  //       from: targetState.doc.line(targetState.doc.lines).from,
  //       to: undefined, // same as targetState.doc.line(targetState.doc.lines).to
  //     },
  //   ];
  // };

  return (
    <>
      <CodeMirror
        value={code}
        extensions={[
          javascript(),
          readOnlyRangesExtension((editorState) => readOnlyRanges),
        ]}
        height="300px"
        onChange={handleChange}
        onCreateEditor={(editorView, editorState) => {
          setEditorView(editorView);
          setEditorState(editorState);
        }}
        theme={copilot}
      />
      <Button
        onClick={() => {
          addReadOnlyRange();
        }}
      >
        Add read-only range
      </Button>
    </>
  );
};

export default CodeEditor;

Checks whether the ranges are correct or are transferred correctly. => Are correct.
